# Explanation of OCaml match and function discrepencies

Tags: function, pattern-matching, ocaml

I am just beginning to learn OCaml and I was playing with just printing out a string.

The snipped that I am running through `ocamlc` is:

```
open Printf;;

type days =
  | Monday
  | Tuesday
  | Wednesday
  | Thursday
  | Friday
  | Saturday
  | Sunday

let string_from_day day = match day with
  | Monday -> "Monday"
  | Tuesday -> "Tuesday"
  | Wednesday -> "Wednesday"
  | Thursday -> "Thursday"
  | Friday -> "Friday"
  | Saturday -> "Saturday"
  | Sunday -> "Sunday"

let d = Monday;;

Printf.printf "The day is %s \n" (string_from_day d);;
```

This runs just fine, it simply prints out `"The day is Monday"`.

But in [*Real World OCaml*](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/variables-and-functions.html) it says that I can define my function with the `function` keyword. So I rewrote my code so that it looked like:

```
open Printf;;

type days =
  | Monday
  | Tuesday
  | Wednesday
  | Thursday
  | Friday
  | Saturday
  | Sunday

let string_from_day day = function
  | Monday -> "Monday"
  | Tuesday -> "Tuesday"
  | Wednesday -> "Wednesday"
  | Thursday -> "Thursday"
  | Friday -> "Friday"
  | Saturday -> "Saturday"
  | Sunday -> "Sunday"

let d = Monday;;

Printf.printf "The day is %s \n" (string_from_day d);;
```

This, however, produces the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type days -> string
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

My question is why? My understanding is that the `string_from_day` function should evaluate to a string in both versions.

When I enter the function into the top level with `match` keyword I get the

```
val string_from_day : days -> bytes = <fun>
```

When I enter the function into the top level with the `function` keyword I get

```
val string_from_day : 'a -> days -> bytes = <fun>
```

I see that the top level result is different for both but the curried function ends in `bytes`, isn't that all that matters? The *Real World OCaml* book says that these are equivalent but it does not seem so. Any explanation or a pointer to more information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the keyword `function`, you mustn't write the argument's name in the function declaration since it's no longer needed. This is what you want to write:

```
let string_of_day = function
  | Monday -> ...
```

Check carefully the example given in RWO:

```
# let some_or_zero = function
    | Some x -> x
    | None -> 0
  ;;

val some_or_zero : int option -> int = <fun>
# List.map ~f:some_or_zero [Some 3; None; Some 4];;
- : int list = [3; 0; 4]
```

The function's declaration doesn't mention an argument. Indeed, it's not needed, since it's immediately given to the pattern-matching.

Note that

```
 let f = function ...
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
 let f x = match x with ...
```

Comment: ahh thank you! I was looking at the next example there too but I see that is a different usage.

Comment: Yes, the keyword `function` replaces the *last* argument. You can still add other arguments before, as shown in RWO. :)

Comment: Note that `function` is not special argument syntax or anything like that, but simply defines a one-argument anonymous function. It is shorthand for `fun x -> match x with ...`.